# Why does the package newtxtext affect caption label numbers and how to avoid it?

Tags: captions, koma-script, newtx

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\slshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Why is the number not slanted? And is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Not all fonts have a slanted shape.

Comment: What does `\textsl{12\textbf{12}}` give? Are the numbers slanted?

Comment: @clemens I see, the numbers are neither slanted nor bold. I guess I should keep my hands off this font then.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments slanted is not supported by `newtxtext`. So an alternative is to go for italics instead, i.e.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\itshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```